# How can i include the separator when calling split()

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, split

I have a list of phone numbers like so:

```
numbers=[
‘(080)3453421256’,
‘(04256)6679345390’,
‘(022)1135643320‘]
```

and i have to get the prefixes of those numbers which have different lengths.
`numbers.split(‘)’, 0)` gives the output without the bracket.
How can i include the bracket and get the prefixes?

Comment: Why not just add the ")" back post-split?

Comment: Looks like you're using rich text quotes. I recommend using plain ascii quotes.

Comment: Can you give an example of your expected output?

Comment: My output —> (080 , (04256, (022 ; Expected output—> (080), (004256), (022)

Comment: At one level of interpretation, you can't: by definition, `split` *removes* the separator.  You can append a new one, but the original is *gone*.  However, *regex* will easily find what you want: "(d+)" -- and will return the matching string without further ado.  Also, please note that you are keeping the *parentheses*; *brackets* are the characters that denote the list.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
for i in numbers:
    a = i.split(")")
    s = a[0]
    print(s[0:]+")",end = ",")
```

Or Try this :

```
for i in numbers:
    a = i.index(")")
    s = i[0:a+1]
    print(s,end = ", ")
```

Output :

```
(080),(04256),(022),
```

Comment: I want to include the brackets. I want the output to look like this: (080), (04256), (022)

Answer (score 0):

Using Python's regular expression package might be more straightforward for you:

```
import re

numbers=[
"(080)3453421256",
"(04256)6679345390",
"(022)1135643320"]

pattern = "\(\d+\)"    # L_PAREN, at least one digit, R_PAREN

for num in numbers:
    print(re.match(pattern, num).group())   # Your data has only one match in each line.
```

Output:

```
(080)
(04256)
(022)
```